# Youtube Data Analytics API Targeted Query For CMS

Tags: youtube-data-api

Before accessing the Youtube API in a script I was using the try-it function for [Targeted Queries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query#try-it). With the most simple params, I keep running into a 400 error.
Scopes:
[image]
Params (CMS name as both the URL and Name failed):
[image]
Errors:
[image]

I am a CMS with full admin privileges and I am a content owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Youtube Targeted Queries, the dimensions and metrics must adhere to specific combinations outlined in the [Content Owner Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports). I suspect using filters for more descriptive (but smaller) reports, and combining reports is a way to maximize on Youtube's rich dimension and metric offerings. Will post a follow up.